# Migration from restful authentication to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, restful-authentication

Currently project uses restful-authentication with different roles. In order to migrate to devise, will I have to create the roles again in devise or is there some way that I can use the code written for restful authentication??

Answer (score 3):

Devise handles only user Authentication, not authorization. To manage roles and permissions, consider using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for permissions and [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) for managing roles.

-- EDIT --

You should also check the devise [wiki page on migrating from restful_auth to devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Migrate-from-restful_authentication-to-Devise). We were able to successfully migrate, without too much pain and rework.

Comment: what should be the proper course for me? Should I get rid of all the restful-authentication logic and start implementing the authentication and authorization from scratch ??